having conflict with TYPO3 version 12.4 when upgrading from 11.5 in composer.json psr/http-message
I was updating a TYPO3 website from version 11.5 to version 12.4 and at first i was having problems with my PHP version so I corrected it in the composer.json file and also in the docker file and restarted my docker, now I went into my terminal and inside of the docker tried to upgrade the composer with the composer update --dry-run command, however I get the following output
typ/toolbox/bc-docker.sh call_composer update --dry-run
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires t3g/blog ^12.0.2 -> satisfiable by t3g/blog[12.0.2].
    - t3g/blog 12.0.2 requires psr/http-message ^1.0 -> satisfiable by psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1, 2.0].
    - tomasnorre/crawler 12.0.4 requires psr/http-message ^2.0 -> satisfiable by psr/http-message[2.0].
    - Root composer.json requires tomasnorre/crawler ^12.0.4 -> satisfiable by tomasnorre/crawler[12.0.4].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

I am trying to find a way I can make both extensions work together because the conflict comes from one needing psr/http-message ^1.0 and the other needing psr/http-message ^2.0.
I was expecting composer to fix the dependency issues by itself. I know it says use option -w but I'm concerned that it will affect my other dependencies.
Part of my composer.json looks like this
"require": {
        "typo3/minimal": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-indexed-search": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^12.4.0",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^12.4.0",
}


The solution seems to fix the version of tomasnorre/crawler to 12.0.3 which require psr/http-message:^1.0
composer require tomasnorre/crawler:12.0.3

but the counterpart is that you can't have the latest correction for the extension tomasnorre/crawler.
But you can also create an issue to ask the t3g/blog owner to upgrade to psr/http-message to version 2.0 too if it's compatible too.
